# React useState -how to set object with arrays?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I cant seem to be able to update an object including arrays. Ive researched and still dont know. Thank you.

the structure of state:

```
items = {
 names: [],
 cities: []
}

const [items, setItems] = useState({});

const update = (categoryName, element) => setItems(...items, [categoryName]: element)
update("names", "mike")
```

this just replaces elements inside array but doesnt add to them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use the callback function and get the last state, like so

```js
const update = (categoryName, element) =>
  setItems((oldItems) => ({
    ...oldItems,
    [categoryName]: [...(oldItems[categoryName] || []), element]
  }));
```

Full example

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState({ names: [] });

  const update = (categoryName, element) =>
    setItems((oldItems) => ({
      ...oldItems,
      [categoryName]: [...(oldItems[categoryName] || []), element]
    }));

  // example to call `update`
  useEffect(() => {
    update("test", "blub");
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {items.test?.map((item) => (
        <p>{item}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: if i try this, i get an error:  Uncaught TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance

Comment: @juliascoding I added a full example, I don't get any errors with that. What is your initial state and how do you call update?

Comment: ah maybe i should have mentioned that earlier, but my initial state is just an object so it would be only {}, not { names: [] }. properties such as names will be added dynamically (yit can be any string you pass to the update function), what is definitite is that those propertys value is always an array. so if i pass as categoryName "names" i always add to the names array, if i pass "cities" such as update("cities", "london"), i either create (if not there yet ''cities') or add to the cities array

Comment: @juliascoding I updated my answer, with an example to set the default value, if no property was found